# Factor-critical graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

$G$ is factor-critical $\Leftrightarrow$ $c_o(G-U) \leq |U|$, $\forall U \subseteq V(G)$ except when $U = \emptyset$ (where $c_o$ is the number of odd components - basically, the RHS means that $U = \emptyset$ violates Tutte's condition)

*My attempt:* ($\Rightarrow$) $G-v$ has a perfect matching $\forall v \in V(G)$. Consider $G' = G-v$ for some arbitrary $v$. Then $c_o(G'-W) = c_o(G - X - v) \leq |W| = |X+v|$, $\forall W \subseteq V(G')$. However, $|W| \geq 1$ since $W = X + v$ for some $v \in V(G)$, $X \subset V(G)$.

I feel like I'm just going in circles and not really getting anywhere, and I don't know how to begin proving the reverse direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of the $\implies$ direction is correct.

For the converse, we must impose the condition that $G$ is connected--otherwise, the condition is satisfied by disjoint two factor-critical graphs (the union will not be factor critical).

Since Tutte's condition does not hold for $U = \varnothing$, $|G|$ is odd.  Remove a vertex $x$ and suppose $G - x$ has no matching.

Set $G - x = H$.  $|H|$ is even, so find a set for which $c_o(H - S) > |S|$.  It suffices to prove that $c_o(H - S) - |S| \ge 2$.  Hover below for the spoiler:

> To show this, it suffices to note that $c_o(H - S)$ and $|S|$ are both even or both odd, since, modulo $2$, they must sum to $|H| \equiv 0$.